# Give the elements of the partially ordered set, which covering relation is:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Give the elements of the partially ordered set, which covering relation is:

$\{(A,B) \in \mathcal{P}(\{a,b,c\})^2:((A=B \cup \{a\})) \vee(A = B  \cup \{b\})) \wedge(A \ne B)\} $

I have some difficulties with this $\mathcal{P}(\{a,b,c\})^2$ part I know that $\mathcal{P}(\{a,b,c\}) =  \{ \emptyset, \{{ a\},\{ b\},\{ c\},\{ a,b\},\{ a,c\},\{ b,c\},\{ a,b,c \} }$

Also the meaning of the second part $((A=B \cup \{a\})) \vee(A = B  \cup \{b\})) \wedge(A \ne B)\}$ is pretty ununderstandable  for me. Should I maybe draw a Hasse diagram?

Comment: What is a covering relation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_relation

Comment: $\mathcal{P}({a,b,c})^2$ is the Cartesian product of $\mathcal{P}({a,b,c})$ by itself, i.e. $\mathcal{P}({a,b,c})\times\mathcal{P}({a,b,c})$. Perhaps drawing a Hasse diagram is useful, but beware: the POSET you are considering has 36 elements, so it could be difficult to draw.

Comment: so what should I do now?